# Error install open CV MacOSX

Tags: macos, python-2.7, opencv

I have problem in install openCV in 83%... My python is 2.7.3. I had habilited xcode. I used this [tuturial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/28/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-2-7/).

My Cmake:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D PYTHON2_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/Furlan/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib \
    -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/Furlan/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ \
    -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python2=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_python3=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

My log:

```
MBP-de-Augusto:build Furlan$ sudo make && sudo make install

[ 66%] Built target example_structured_light_capsinpattern
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_structured_light
[ 66%] Built target opencv_test_structured_light
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_structured_light_cap_pattern
[ 66%] Built target example_structured_light_cap_pattern
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_structured_light_projectorcalibration
[ 66%] Built target example_structured_light_projectorcalibration
[ 66%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_tracking.dylib
[ 67%] Built target opencv_tracking
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_introduction_to_tracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_tracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tracker_dataset
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_tracker_dataset
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_multiTracker_dataset
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_multitracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_benchmark
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_benchmark
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_multitracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_multitracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_kcf
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_kcf
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_tracking
[ 67%] Built target opencv_test_tracking
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_tutorial_customizing_cn_tracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_tracking_goturnTracker
[ 67%] Built target example_tracking_goturnTracker
[ 67%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_tracking
[ 67%] Built target opencv_perf_tracking
[ 67%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videostab.dylib
[ 68%] Built target opencv_videostab
[ 68%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_xfeatures2d.dylib
[ 69%] Built target opencv_xfeatures2d
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_pct_signatures
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_pct_signatures
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_pct_webcam
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_pct_webcam
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 70%] Built target opencv_perf_xfeatures2d
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_video_homography
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_video_homography
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_surf_matcher
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_shape_transformation
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 70%] Built target opencv_test_xfeatures2d
[ 70%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification
[ 70%] Built target example_xfeatures2d_bagofwords_classification
[ 70%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_ximgproc.dylib
[ 72%] Built target opencv_ximgproc
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_thinning
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_thinning
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_seeds
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_seeds
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_niblack_thresholding
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_niblack_thresholding
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_selectivesearchsegmentation_demo
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_selectivesearchsegmentation_demo
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_structured_edge_detection
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_structured_edge_detection
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_graphsegmentation_demo
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_graphsegmentation_demo
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_slic
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_slic
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_fld_lines
[ 72%] Built target example_ximgproc_fld_lines
[ 72%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_ximgproc
[ 73%] Built target opencv_perf_ximgproc
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_filterdemo
[ 73%] Built target example_ximgproc_filterdemo
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_disparity_filtering
[ 73%] Built target example_ximgproc_disparity_filtering
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_fast_hough_transform
[ 73%] Built target example_ximgproc_fast_hough_transform
[ 73%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_ximgproc
[ 74%] Built target opencv_test_ximgproc
[ 74%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_live_demo
[ 75%] Built target example_ximgproc_live_demo
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_paillou_demo
[ 75%] Built target example_ximgproc_paillou_demo
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_ximgproc_deriche_demo
[ 75%] Built target example_ximgproc_deriche_demo
[ 75%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_aruco.dylib
[ 75%] Built target opencv_aruco
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_detect_markers
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_detect_markers
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_aruco
[ 75%] Built target opencv_test_aruco
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_detect_diamonds
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_detect_diamonds
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_detect_board
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_detect_board
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_create_marker
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_create_marker
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_create_board
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_create_board
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_calibrate_camera
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_calibrate_camera
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_create_diamond
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_create_diamond
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_calibrate_camera_charuco
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_calibrate_camera_charuco
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_detect_board_charuco
[ 75%] Built target example_aruco_detect_board_charuco
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_aruco_create_board_charuco
[ 76%] Built target example_aruco_create_board_charuco
[ 76%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_optflow.dylib
[ 77%] Built target opencv_optflow
[ 77%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_gpc_evaluate
[ 77%] Built target example_optflow_gpc_evaluate
[ 77%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_pcaflow_demo
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_pcaflow_demo
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_gpc_train
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_gpc_train
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_optical_flow_evaluation
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_optical_flow_evaluation
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_optflow
[ 78%] Built target opencv_perf_optflow
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_simpleflow_demo
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_simpleflow_demo
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_optflow
[ 78%] Built target opencv_test_optflow
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_motempl
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_motempl
[ 78%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/example_optflow_dis_opticalflow
[ 78%] Built target example_optflow_dis_opticalflow
[ 78%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_stitching.dylib
[ 79%] Built target opencv_stitching
[ 79%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_stitching
[ 79%] Built target opencv_test_stitching
[ 79%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_stitching
[ 80%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
[ 80%] Generating pyopencv_generated_include.h, pyopencv_generated_funcs.h, pyopencv_generated_types.h, pyopencv_generated_type_reg.h, pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h
/bin/sh: /bin/python: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [modules/python2/pyopencv_generated_include.h] Error 127
make[1]: *** [modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar error. There must be a build.make file in `opencv/build/modules/python2/CMakeFiles/opencv_python2.dir/`

Search the line where it tries to generate `pyopencv_generated_include.h, pyopencv_generated_funcs.h, pyopencv_generated_types.h, pyopencv_generated_type_reg.h, pyopencv_generated_ns_reg.h`

It uses a python script, something like gen2.py

Search for that file. eg in my case it was located in `opencv/modules/python/src2`

Check the first line and make sure that it has your python executable path